# Value of a variable does not change - add function

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, loop

We want to add +1 to the variable @times when the if conditions are true but the variable stays at 1 in our AMPScript.

Following code causing me some headaches:

```
%%[SET @times=1]%%
%%[SET @one=1]%%
%%[SET @moveindate= Request__c:Moveindate__c]%%
%%[
set @rows = LookupRows('Apartment_Master','City__c',@City__c, 'Number_of_bedrooms__c', @Number_of_bedrooms__c,'Has_Availability__c','true','Online_and_verified__c','true') 
SET @rowcount = RowCount(@rows) 

FOR @i = 1 to 20 DO 
  SET @appartment = Row(@rows,@i) 
  SET @.... 
]%%

%%[IF @appartment_available >= @moveindate AND @times!=5 THEN]%%
%%[@times=Add(@times,@one)]%%

/* a lot of actions */

%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

Does anybody know the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having `AND @times!=1` on your if statement, you are making it impossible for your condition to be true.

1. You set times to 1.
2. You set a conditional that if x >= y AND times is not 1

   (which is always false as you previously set times to 1)
3. times can never increase as the addition statement is inside the conditional

You should likely revisit your logic and either reposition your math, reconfigure your conditional or both.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. The code has been from a test. Means, that has not been the correct code I wanted to show you but it is okay, I already found the answer. Post it, downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the answer for the add +1 problem, but I found a solution that fits to my problem. I just need 4 correct data sets, so I made it iterative.

```
%%[SET @times=1]%%
%%[SET @moveindate= Request__c:Moveindate__c]%%

%%[ SET @City__c = Request__c:Apartment__r:City__c SET @Number_of_bedrooms__c = Request__c:Apartment__r:Number_of_bedrooms__c SET @rows = LookupRows('Apartment_Master_Homelike','City__c',@City__c, 'Number_of_bedrooms__c', @Number_of_bedrooms__c,'Has_Availability__c','true','Online_and_verified__c','true') SET @rowcount = RowCount(@rows) FOR @i = 1 to @rowcount DO SET @appartment = Row(@rows,@i) SET @appartment_price = FIELD(@appartment,'Price__c') SET @appartment_title = FIELD(@appartment,'Title_DE__c') SET @appartment_area = FIELD(@appartment,'Living_Area__c') SET @appartment_available = FIELD(@appartment,'Available_From__c') SET @appartment_picture = FIELD(@appartment,'Cover_picture__c') SET @appartment_bedrooms = FIELD(@appartment,'Number_of_bedrooms__c') SET @appartment_city = FIELD(@appartment,'City__c') SET @appartment_link = FIELD(@appartment,'Link__c') ]%%

%%[IF @appartment_available <= @moveindate AND @times<@i AND @times !=5 THEN]%%

 %%[IF @times==1 THEN]%%
     %%[SET @times=2]%% 
   %%[ELSEIF @times==2 THEN]%%
     %%[SET @times=3]%% 
   %%[ELSEIF @times==3 THEN]%%
     %%[SET @times=4]%% 
   %%[ELSEIF @times==4 THEN]%%
     %%[SET @times=5]%% 
 %%[ENDIF]%% 

   /* a lot of actions */

%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```